# How can we avoid existing EBS volumes from being deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform 1.1.3 with aws provider 3.75.2 to create TF code for the existing 2-node infra. The code snippet is like below:

```
module:
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "backend-logs" {
  count = var.create_ebs_log_volumes ? var.backend_nodes_qty : 0

  availability_zone = element(data.aws_subnet.backend.*.availability_zone, count.index)
  size              = var.volume_log_size
  type              = var.ebs_volume_type
  encrypted         = var.ebs_enable_encryption
  kms_key_id        = var.ebs_encryption_key_id
}
```

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "backend-logs" {
  count       = var.backend_nodes_qty
  device_name = "/dev/sdf"
  volume_id   = element(module.xyz.backend_ebs_volume_log_ids, count.index)
  instance_id = element(module.xyz.backend_instance_ids, count.index)
}
```

and I've imported the instance/volume/attachment resources successfully.

```
terraform import module.xyz.aws_ebs_volume.backend-logs[0] vol-0123456789abcedf0
terraform import module.xyz.aws_ebs_volume.backend-logs[1] vol-0123456789abcedf1
terraform import aws_volume_attachment.backend-logs[0] /dev/sdf:vol-0123456789abcedf0:i-0123456789abcedf0
terraform import aws_volume_attachment.backend-logs[1] /dev/sdf:vol-0123456789abcedf1:i-0123456789abcedf1
```

When I run `terraform plan`, the plan tells me that the volumes are going to be destroyed. How can we avoid that? thanks

```
  # aws_volume_attachment.backend-logs[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_volume_attachment" "backend-logs" {
      ~ id          = "vai-1993905001" -> (known after apply)
      ~ volume_id   = "vol-0123456789abcedf0" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # aws_volume_attachment.backend-logs[1] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_volume_attachment" "backend-logs" {
      ~ id          = "vai-1955292002" -> (known after apply)
      ~ volume_id   = "vol-0123456789abcedf1" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
    
  # module.xyz.aws_ebs_volume.backend-logs[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_ebs_volume" "backend-logs" {
      ~ arn                  = "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:1234567890:volume/vol-0123456789abcedf0" -> (known after apply)
      ~ availability_zone    = "us-west-2a" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      ~ id                   = "vol-0123456789abcedf0" -> (known after apply)
      ~ iops                 = 150 -> (known after apply)
      + kms_key_id           = (known after apply)
      - multi_attach_enabled = false -> null
      + snapshot_id          = (known after apply)
      ~ throughput           = 0 -> (known after apply)
        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # module.xyz.aws_ebs_volume.backend-logs[1] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_ebs_volume" "backend-logs" {
      ~ arn                  = "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:1234567890:volume/vol-0123456789abcedf1" -> (known after apply)
      ~ availability_zone    = "us-west-2b" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
      ~ id                   = "vol-0123456789abcedf1" -> (known after apply)
      ~ iops                 = 150 -> (known after apply)
      + kms_key_id           = (known after apply)
      - multi_attach_enabled = false -> null
      + snapshot_id          = (known after apply)
      ~ throughput           = 0 -> (known after apply)
        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Comment: Has the Availability Zone changed, because it says that's the reason for the resources to be replaced?

Comment: Not likely. I've checked the states and `backend-logs[0]` is in `us-west-2a` while the other is in `us-west-2b`.
Could this code flip the AZ?

Comment: Probably not, but I was thinking that you might be trying to deploy in another region which has different AZs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue relates to AZ stuff. You can try the workaround by adding these lines in aws_instance block.

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [ availability_zone ]
  }
```

Comment: yeah, `ignore_changes` worked around the issue.

It still doesn't make sense to me because the AZ didn't change.

What if AZ needs to be changed in other cases?